# Facebook deep linking on Android app engagement campaign

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'd like to create an ad on Facebook that targets mobile users in order to engage them with my app. The ad must open my app when the user clicks on it in case the app is already installed. Otherwise, it must take him to the Play Store.

I read the following tutorial that shows how to achieve what I want using a news feed story.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/link-to-your-native-app

Unfortunately, it doesn't say anything about ads. I also read about app install campaigns, but they are only shown to people who don't have my app installed.

I want to offer discounts through my app to a segmented group of people on Facebook. That's why I need a campaign that handles deep linking and app installs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it seems to be supported:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads-engagement/